# which video format is bessed for flat graphical animations

Tags: video, ffmpeg, graphics, mp4, webm

If i were to create an mp4 out of an svg animation, much of the color data in the output is the same, in PNG compression you can significantly reduce file size by reducing color. What I love about PNG is that the images always have a beautiful flat color / consistent look to them as opposed to jpegs which look very messy after antialiasing etc. (in the case of graphics to clarify). My feeling about .mp4 is that the compression technique results in frames that look "messy" like jpegs do when representing flat graphics or text. Is there a better codec out there? Is this what webm does well?
Thanks in advance for the input!

Comment: There are so many formats out there that to provide a useful answer we need more information. How are you going to use the resulting file? Are you restricted to certain formats? We need more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) A little more clarification please...

But:

Here is what I have used in the past to get uncompressed or minimally compressed images:
PNG with little or no compression. Try setting the 'q' range very tight like -qmin 1 -qmax 2, adjust other parameters around this.

Use a format that that has no compression at all, and is capable of rendering pixel by pixel. Setting the 'q' range low and tight gives better images with bigger file size.

Another possibility is to set -gop to something like 1.

If you want compression and want to know best codec for that, some may be better than others, but all will rely on you setting the encoding parameters.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll try to edit my question more, but your answer really helps me get going in the right direction!